# Sql server automatically change password

Tags: password, sql-server-2008-r2

I have sql server 2008 R2. Everytime I create new sql server authorization login, whatever password I write it was changed to unknown me 15 characters password. Same is for sa. So I can't lofin with sql server authorization.I login with windows authorization and I have sysadmin permissions. How can I fixed that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `Enforce Password Policy` is not enabled

In other words

```
CREATE LOGIN loginName WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>', 
CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

Also is SQL Server running in Mixed Mode?