# Sql Server user password changes by itself

Tags: sql-server, password, users, reset

This the same question as this:

[Sql server automatically change password](https://serverfault.com/questions/264961/sql-server-automatically-change-password)

However, the user never specified how he fixed it, he only said that he fixed it.  I am having the exact same issue.  Whenever I try to create a new user login and password, the password immediately changes to an unknown, 15-character password.

@Aram Gevorgyan was the original poster of the question

EDIT:
I create a new login like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoSXT.png) and click ok

Then if I check the properties for the login immediately after, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1WmT.png)

I am using windows 10 and just installed the newest version of sql server express and sql server management studio

Comment: Did you tried the solution that has been given to that post in the answer?

Comment: Yes, and the answer given did not help.  I'm not sure why he marked it as the answer when he said that it didn't work.

Comment: I have the same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to do what Aaron mentioned about and after that press RMB on your server name and choose restart, it works for me, after server will restart disconnect from it and reconnect with your new creds.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/523214)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be able to be more precise if you'd edit your question with as many details as you can.

With the provided details that's what I can answer; too long for comments.

This really looks like some kind of security related issue. Have you turned on logging? What does logs look like? Have you tried having the network cable unplugged for a while until the password "automagically" changes? This may lead to identify the threat as a local or a network one. You didn't provide any detail at all in your question regarding your system nor your environment nor your applications working on dbs. Without any of those it's impossible to get rid of your issue and I can guarantee you that you'll get quickly downvoted even if the question itself is an interesting one. I'd try to scan this server for virus/malware/scripts/unknown services then I would come back here editing the question with as many details as possible.

To confirm that I'm right, just bring up a Ms Windows Server VM, install Sql in evaluation mode, restore your dbs, create your users, set passwords and I ensure you passwords won't "automagically" change.

Comment: I think it might be a settings issue.  When I click ok to save my changes, I'll click properties and the password will change back to the same default 15-character  password that I don't know

Comment: I don't think such a setting exists in Ms Sql Server.

Comment: I edited the question to give you some more details

Comment: After your edit, I understand that you think that the password changes just because the number of asterisk that are used to hide it changes. This is a normal and expected behavior for a password field, otherwise anybody looking at an hidden password would know how long it is and that would be a security concern.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now.  Thank you very much. I'm still getting error 18456, but at least I know now, I'll try to look up the error

Comment: @jdwee did you found my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't enabled SQL server authentication. Right-click on your server name in SQL Server Management Services then go to properties.  In the security security section enable SQL Server and Windows Authentication.  Click OK and restart your server.

Comment: still not working..